# Enable TRY style error handling

Tags: sql-server

Is there a `SET` command or similar I can enable to get the same error handling as a try/catch block? Specifically halting the script/procedure on the first error.

The only way I've currently found so far is to wrap the whole query in a try/catch such as

```
BEGIN TRY
    -- procedure body goes here
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    THROW;
END CATCH
```

While this hack does work to enable the correct error handling behaviour it just feels wrong to have a catch block that just re-throws the error.

In this particular case there's nothing more I need to do with the error other than halt the script and throw the error back out to the script runner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on whether you want to abort the entire batch. If you want to entirely abort the batch and since you don't want to go ahead with try catch, XACT_Abort will do the trick for you:

```
create table test1
(id int);

create proc usp_test
as
begin
    set nocount on
    set xact_abort on

    insert into test1 
    select 1

    select 1/0

    select 1
end
```

Now try to execute the procedure and also you will see Select does not succeded

```
exec usp_test

select * from test1
```

Further Throw, raiserror also gives me the same behaviour, but I always tend to use set `Xact_abort on` if I want my transaction to rollback entirely even in case of timeouts. Further MSDN page has more info:

> The THROW statement honors SET XACT_ABORT RAISERROR does not. New Applications should use THROW instead of RAISERROR.

Below link gives you more idea on advantages of using xact_abort: 
[What is the benefit of using “SET XACT_ABORT ON” in a stored procedure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150032/what-is-the-benefit-of-using-set-xact-abort-on-in-a-stored-procedure)

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion you should use TRY/CATCH every time when you have update, insert or delete statements. This has saved me a lot of headaches. Check this -- [1](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/10/03/sql-server-2005-explanation-of-try%E2%80%A6catch-and-error-handling-with-raiseerror-function/)

Comment: I want the try/catch behaviour but without having to write a catch block that's only purpose is to re-throw the error. In this case the try/catch block is just a hack to ensure the try/catch behaviour of halting the script and propagating the error to the caller.

Answer (score -3):

Take a look at `SET XACT_ABORT` option.

Comment: That will work in some cases, but can't be used in conjunction with save points (i.e. `SAVE TRANSACTION foo; ...; ROLLBACK TRANSACTION foo`)